# how will I get new shekel symbol in iso-8859-8 perl

Tags: perl, translation, currency

I am using i18n/locales/he_IL (iso-8859-8 )for translation in perl. But I couldn't get new shekel symbol using this. How will I get new shekel symbol the same in perl?

I am using this code

*currency_symbol    "<U05E9><U05D7>".*

I also tried with 
currency_symbol "<U20AA>"

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you perhaps referring to U+20AA, NEW SHEQEL SIGN (₪)? It's not part of the [iso-8859-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8) character set. You cannot insert it into a document encoded using iso-8859-8.

XML and HTML have a mechanism for including characters outside of the document's character set. To include this character in an iso-8859-8 XML or HTML document, you can use `&#x20AA;`.

If you just want to create a Perl string with that character, you can use

```
my $s = "\N{NEW SHEQEL SIGN}";
   or
my $s = chr(0x20AA);
```